# Can someone rate and critique my map?

Tags: map-making

this is my first time making a map or even world building, I tried to follow as much as i could some YouTube tutorial and created this map. Can someone give me tips and how to improve the map. Thanks!

There are the resources:

Gold - yellow
Copper - white/gray
Lead - Blue
Iron - light pink
Silver -Red
Tin - light blue

The circles are major cities.

I placed the resources in the map description!

Ignore the big white square.

[image: Map]

Comment: Please attach the map as an image here. And ask for something specific. You are asking for opinions, and we don't answer opinion based questions.

Comment: In what way are he rivers flowing? traditionally rivers flow downhill but your river system seems a bit flat.

Comment: "Critique" isn't really a very useful thing to ask for, here. If there isn't really a good metric for what distinguishes a right answer from a wrong answer, or a good answer from a _really_ good answer, then your question is probably not a good fit for the site. A better question might look like "_where are realistic places for iron ore deposits on my world map_", maybe.

Comment: This looks like you used MS-Paint onto an existing map. First rue of mapmaking: Work ith a program that allows layers.

Answer (score 3):

My big issue is your mountains.   Typically large ranges form on one side of a continent.   The Western Mountains would not fork like that nor would the eastern mountains curve as they do up north.

Your mountains also cause issue with your rivers.  The western major river flows through a valley but given the proximity, it's not likely they'd go out to sea (rivers flow to the ocean and down hill.   There is not enough space to have enough land to flow.  It could be a platea but these look like ranges, not a sudden rising elevation.   You also have a porblem with how all that water gets there because weather typically travels west to east or east to west depending on whether your position with respect to the equator and the tropics and arctic circles (0 to Tropics it's the direction of the setting sun, tropics to arctic it's the direction opposite of the setting sun, and above arctic, it's sun setting direction).   Either way, the mountains on both coasts would mean the interior is desert with no rain that would penetrate the ground and replenish the source of the springs or the rivers.   And yes, the U.S. does have an eastern and western mountain range but the eastern range (Appalachia) is more of really really big hills when compared to the Rocky Mountains (The Rockies are actually the North American prortion of the same super chain that becomes the Andes in South America.  The Super Chain goes from the tip of Argentina and Chile and all the way up to Canada.)

Mountains are also important in river directins as the are typically continental water divides.   The Rockies in North America are an imaginary line where water will flow either east or west depending on which side of the mountains it falls o.  So if all rivers flow north to south, it will likely form a large mouth, rather than three smaller ones.  Look at the Amazon River.  In South America, the Andes are so close to the coast that almost all water flows west to and most of that water flows to the Amazon River's mouth, which is why it expels more water than any other river in the world... and fun fact, but by the time all the tributaries actually converge into the Amazon river, there is already more water flowing in the river than any other river in the world... and it's still got more water to collect.

Comment: *"Large ranges form on one side of a continent":* with such examples as the Carpathians and the Balkans in Europe, the ancient Urals, the Pamirs, the Altai, the Tian-Shan, the Hindukush and the Himalayas in Asia, or the Rwenzori and the Tibesti in Africa. Surprisingly, not all the world looks like the Americas.

Comment: @AlexP:  Most of those are on continental divides.   The Urals are typically the area where Russia stops being "Europe" and starts being "Asia".  The Himialayas are also a result of two continental plates smushing together (The Indian Sub Continent and the Asia Continent, specifically) and is part of the reason why the peaks are ridiculously tall.

Comment: @hszmw: Which only shows that what is shown on the map as a continent is not guaranteed to made of one single ancient piece... Which is why you cannot just look  at a map and say that mountain ranges are in the wrong place. On the contrary, you look at the map and imagine the geological history which put the mountain ranges there. (And geologically speaking Europe is a large peninsula of Asia; there is one single Eurasian tectonic plate. The Urals really are *ancient*; they were risen in the Paleozoic, in a world very different from ours.)